# Print a raw pathname structure

Tags: common-lisp

Using CCL, when I print a pathname using, e.g., `(format t "~s" pathname)`, or with `pprint`, or with `print`, it prints out with the `#P` reader syntax.  For instance:

```
? (make-pathname :directory "foo")
#P"foo/"
? (format t "~s" (make-pathname :directory "foo"))
#P"foo/"
NIL
```

I'd really like to see the underlying pathname structure, so that I can tell exactly what the object looks like.  Is there a way to print it raw?

Comment: Just guessing: try setting `*pretty-print*`, `*print-escape*` and/or `*print-readably*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if that's what you're looking for, but you could [call the inspector](http://trac.clozure.com/ccl/wiki/CommandLineInspect)

```
(inspect thing)
```

CCL example:

```
? (inspect (make-pathname :directory "foo"))
[0]     #P"foo/"
[1]     Type: PATHNAME
[2]     Class: #<BUILT-IN-CLASS PATHNAME>
[3]     TYPE: (PATHNAME . #<CCL::CLASS-WRAPPER PATHNAME #x14083886>)
[4]     %PATHNAME-DIRECTORY: (:RELATIVE "foo")
[5]     %PATHNAME-NAME: NIL
[6]     %PATHNAME-TYPE: NIL
[7]     %PHYSICAL-PATHNAME-VERSION: NIL
[8]     %PHYSICAL-PATHNAME-DEVICE: NIL
Inspect> help
The following toplevel commands are available:
 <n>    the same as (:I <n>)
 (:S N V)  set the <n>th line of object data to value <v>
 :HOME   show first page of object data
 :PREV   show previous page of object data
 :NEXT   show next page of object data
 :SHOW   re-show currently inspected object (the value of CCL:@)
 :Q     exit inspector
 :POP   exit current inspector level
 (:I N)  inspect <n>th item
 :?     help
 :PWD   Print the pathame of the current directory
 (:CD DIR)  Change to directory DIR (e.g., #p"ccl:" or "/some/dir")
 (:PROC &OPTIONAL P)  Show information about specified process <p>/all processes
 (:KILL P)  Kill process whose name or ID matches <p>
 (:Y &OPTIONAL P)  Yield control of terminal-input to process
whose name or ID matches <p>, or to any process if <p> is null
Any other form is evaluated and its results are printed out.
Inspect>
```

[Example on ideone with CLISP](http://ideone.com/vPMg7q)

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Answer (score 7):

In addition to `inspect`, you can use `describe`:

```
? (describe #P"/tmp/**/file.*")
#P"/tmp/**/file.*"
Type: PATHNAME
Class: #<BUILT-IN-CLASS PATHNAME>
TYPE: (PATHNAME . #<CCL::CLASS-WRAPPER PATHNAME #x30004003ED0D>)
%PATHNAME-DIRECTORY: (:ABSOLUTE "tmp" :WILD-INFERIORS)
%PATHNAME-NAME: "file"
%PATHNAME-TYPE: :WILD
%PHYSICAL-PATHNAME-VERSION: :NEWEST
%PHYSICAL-PATHNAME-DEVICE: NIL
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with format directives, change "S" with "A" that prints the string, "S" (try to) prints a valid object that can read the REPL or the function read

```
; SLIME 2016-04-19
CL-USER> (format t "~s" (make-pathname :directory "foo"))
#P"/foo/"
NIL
CL-USER> (format t "~A" (make-pathname :directory "foo"))
/foo/
NIL
```

from the tutorial a [few format receipes](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html)

> "~S" tries to generate output that can be read back in with READ.
>   Thus, strings will be enclosed in quotation marks, symbols will be
>   package-qualified when necessary, and so on. Objects that don't have a
>   READable representation are printed with the unreadable object syntax
>   "<>." With a colon modifier, both the ~A and ~S directives emit NIL as
>   () rather than NIL. Both the ~A and ~S directives also take up to
>   four prefix parameters, which can be used to control whether padding is > added after (or before with the at-sign modifier) the value, but those
>   parameters are only really useful for generating tabular data.

finally only to get the string put nil instead of t wich redirect to standard output

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~A" (make-pathname :directory "foo"))
"/foo/"
```

Comment: what is the problem with this answer?

Comment: I suspect that the question was more about the pathname structure and less about getting rid of the `#p` prefix.

Comment: "I'd really like to see the underlying pathname structure, so that I can tell exactly what the object looks like" ... getting rid of the prefix is not the issue, the OP wants to see the object and not a human friendly presentation (`~a`). A pathname is far more complex than a simple string, see http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/19_b.htm